# Loading XML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, html, filter, xml-parsing

I'm working on a dog web site with a XML back-end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<breeder>
 <dog>
<dogs_id>001</dogs_id>
<dogs_image>../images/eclipse.jpg</dogs_image>
<dogs_breeding_name>Eclipse</dogs_breeding_name>
<dogs_given_name>Coco</dogs_given_name>
<sex>female</sex>
<dogs_mom>Juno</dogs_mom>
<dogs_dad>Brutus</dogs_dad>
<dogs_pedigree>../Pedigrees/pedigree - kodiak.jpg</dogs_pedigree>
<dogs_pedigree_status>Active</dogs_pedigree_status>
<alaa_registration>ALAA - 000000</alaa_registration>
<microchip_no>0000</microchip_no>
<eye_colour>Copper</eye_colour>
<colour_genetics>bbEE, kyky, ata, Ssp</colour_genetics>
<coat_colour>Chocolate and Tan Phantom</coat_colour>
<adult_height>16"</adult_height>
<coat_type></coat_type>
<adult_weight>20lbs</adult_weight>
<size>Mini</size>
<profile>Words about Kodiak</profile>
<breeders_notes></breeders_notes>
 </dog>

  <dog>
<dogs_id>002</dogs_id>
<dogs_image>../images/danny.jpg</dogs_image>
<dogs_breeding_name>Danny Boy</dogs_breeding_name>
<dogs_given_name>Danny</dogs_given_name>
<sex>male</sex>
<dogs_mom>Doodle's Rosie</dogs_mom>
<dogs_dad>Dehler's Jack </dogs_dad>
<dogs_pedigree>../Pedigrees/pedigree - danny.jpg</dogs_pedigree>
<dogs_pedigree_status>Active</dogs_pedigree_status>
<alaa_registration>ALAA- 000000</alaa_registration>
<microchip_no></microchip_no>
<colour_genetics>Bbee, kyky, atat</colour_genetics>
<eye_colour></eye_colour>
<coat_colour>Very Dark Red, invisible phantom</coat_colour>
<adult_height>16"</adult_height>
<coat_type></coat_type>
<adult_weight></adult_weight>
<size>Mini</size>
<profile>Words about Danny</profile>
<breeders_notes></breeders_notes>
</dog>
```

I can get the XML to load in a table but I want to be able to move each of the fields around and filter the data on the field "sex" for "male and female".

This is the code I have used on my HTML page to load the XML.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "../xml/dogs.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
        $(".dogs-info").children().remove;// to clear the text field
       success: xmlParser
     });

     function xmlParser(xml) {
     $(xml).find("dog").each(function () {
            var i= $(this);
            var profileText= (i).find("profile").text()

            $(".dogs-info").append('<html>' + profileText +        '</html>');

        });          
        }
      </script>
```

3 Questions
    1. Why isn't the XML loading into this page?
    2. How would I filter the data on the field "sex" for either male or female.
    3. I come from the ActionScript world is there a substitute for trace()?

Hope someone can help :-) thanks for reading if you made it this far!

Comment: Look in browser dev tools console. If code shown is accurate it will throw error because you can't put statements in the middle of an object. `$(".dogs-info").children().remove;` needs to be moved out of object

Comment: Good tip thanks. I have moved it to inside the xmlParser, It's still not working but Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have `$(".dogs-info").children().remove;` smack in the middle of an AJAX request object; that needs to be somewhere else like the first line of `xmlParser`.
2. You don't have a closing `});` for `$(document).ready( function() {`
3. Why are you putting `profileText` inside `<html>` tags?

Comment: Number 1.- I moved the line to where you suggested. I also added the closing tag for the first function and removed the <HTML>tags. I used this on a past project that required them. Still not working but thanks for your suggestions.